# Android Edit text field

Tags: android, edit

Is it possible to create edit text field in android keep constant in always.?i want to store my login id always constant even reboot the application

Comment: put your loginId inside sharedpreferecences

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store some constant (take extreme care to password and do not use this!) you should use SharedPreference

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
sharedPrefs.getString("prefUsername", "NULL");
```

is the code to retrieve the preference.

You can write it by using a PreferenceActivity, or more complicated (but still really easy) use an EditText and the [Editor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html)

You should be able to find informations in the official documentation, I cannot write the whole stuff here, because STackOverflow is not meant to be a tutorial website.